# Javascript, promise.then() function executed first

Tags: javascript, promise

I apologize in advance for overlooking something fundamental but I can't get my head around the following issue.

I want to create a user on the server, subsequently showing all users (including the new one). To simplify things I have put an alert in the "then" clause. The problem is that the 
alert comes up before the "CreateUser" on the server has completed. According to the doc, "then" is executed when the promise has completed.
Why is it the inverse on my pc ?

```
function createUser(newUser) {   
    userService.create(newUser) // Post creating new user
        .then(      
        alert('Why do I come up before completion of the  userService.create() function  ?')
        );  
}
```

This is the userService.create() function:

```
function create(user) {
//    alert(user);
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { ...authHeader(), 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: user
    };

    return fetch('/Client/Create', requestOptions).then(handleResponse, handleError);
}
```

handleResponse:

```
function handleResponse(response) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

....
```

handleError:

```
function handleError(error) {
    return Promise.reject(error && error.message);
}
```

Thanks a million.

Comment: You're directly calling alert, you need to put a functin that calls alert in your then method

Comment: `.then(()=>{alert('...')})`

Comment: @DanielKrom That's it! Thank you very much. EC6 syntax, even more elegant than using a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
function createUser(newUser) {   
    userService.create(newUser) // Post creating new user
        .then(      
        alert('Why do I come up before completion of the  userService.create() function  ?')
        );  
}
```

to:

```
function createUser(newUser) {   
    userService.create(newUser) // Post creating new user
        .then(function(){
          alert('Why do I come up before completion of the  userService.create() function  ?');
        });  
}
```

[then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: You are a hero. I was pulling my hairs out.

Answer (score 1):

`then` requires a function to be passed, so do this:

```
userService.create(newUser).then(() => {
    alert('Why do I come up before completion of the  userService.create() function  ?')
});
```